# WPF listbox binding to List<string> or List<string[]>

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collections, listbox

- I'm very new to WPF (especially XAML) *

Hello, my app has a class which gets bunch of comma separated string. So I made a List collection to store the strings. Also, I made DataTemplate for the listbox.  Here is code.

MainWindow.xaml

```
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AAA}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BBB}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CCC}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
...
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="309" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="216" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource HeadlineDataTemplate}"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
...
MyClass myClass;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myClass = new MyClass();
}
...
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myClass.getData(Textbox1.Text); // I want to convert this to add items to listbox1.
}
```

MyClass.cs

```
...
public void getData(string target)
{
    List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
    ...
    while(result != null)
    {
        // This loop gives bunch of comma separated string (more than 100)
        itemList.Add(result);
    }
    // after the loop, itemList has
    // itemList[0] = {"AAA1,BBB1,CCC1"}
    // itemList[1] = {"AAA2,BBB2,CCC2"}
    // itemList[2] = {"AAA3,BBB3,CCC3"}
    // ...
    // I also can store the strings to List<string[]> using string.split().

}
```

So how should I do this?

I couldn't find the answer on the internet.

Comment: i would start with undersanding data binding, google several simple exampls such as this (follow the links) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912846/tutorials-for-binding-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create a model class to represent each ListBox Item. In this example I name it `MyListBoxItemModel` :

```
public class MyListBoxItemModel
{
    public string AAA { get; set; }
    public string BBB { get; set; }
    public string CCC { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `getData` function, create List of `MyListBoxItemModel` to be listbox1's `ItemsSource` :

```
public void getData(string target)
{
    List<MyListBoxItemModel> itemList = new List<MyListBoxItemModel>();
    ...
    while(result != null)
    {
        var splittedResult = result.Split(',');
        itemList.Add(new MyListBoxItemModel{ 
                                AAA = splittedResult[0], 
                                BBB = splittedResult[1], 
                                CCC = splittedResult[2] 
                            });
    }
    listbox1.ItemsSource = itemList;
}
```

Note that this example only demonstrates minimum amount of code needed to get your data displayed in the `ListBox`. Not involving various techniques and best practices around WPF development, such as implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, MVVM pattern, etc.

Comment: I thought about this, but would it make my app slower? cause it creates instance every each time in the while loop.

Comment: I don't think so. Because it is just a plain class with no logic in it's constructor. So far I see that binding to model is more common practice then binding to array of string

Answer (score 1):

you can just bind to public properties, so if you write something like

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding BBB}" />
```

you need an object with a public property "BBB".

so in addition to the answer from har07 you should also use a public property for your list(OberservableCollection)

```
 public OberservableCollection<MyListBoxItemModel> ItemList {get;set;}
```

then your binding for your itemscontrol can look like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource HeadlineDataTemplate}"/>
```

all you need now is the right datacontext ;)

Comment: Thanks! What's the benefit of using ObservableCollection?

Comment: observablecollection implement notification for Add() Remove(), Clear() - so you see all changes in your collection in your view.